# If condition based on cell value in excel using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

There are two excel files, where the data on condition should be appended to another excel file.

**CONDITION:** If Any value in Column A is equal to 'x' then it should get value from col B and get it appended directly to col A/B in excel file 2.

The below table is present in Excel File 1.

[image]

The below should be the output... which is in Excel file 2.

[image]

Am new to this.. please help with this code, and preferably if code is done using "Openpyxl", it would be much helpful !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a little confusing to see "column A" not referring to the first column. In such cases it is better to make more explicit references. You should also include your own code.

Answer (score 1):

A slight improvement on Redox's solution:

```py
import openpyxl
#Open Input File open (file1)
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1['Sheet1']

wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active
ws2.append(["Base", "A/B"])

for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=3, values_only=True):
    base, a, b = row
    if a != "x":
        new_row = [base, a]
    else:
        new_row = [base, b]
    ws2.append(new_row)
```

Ideally you should also check that the third column has a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

So, a simple solution and a more complicated one:

[image]

Then between files you can use a link or index() or indirect().

Comment: I want it as a python code not as in excel.  Anyways thnks for replying.

Comment: @Lote_marsk_chozey you tagged Excel...

Comment: Yes its for a excel file to automate using python

Answer (score 0):

To do this using python-openpyxl, you can use the below code... added comments so it is easy to understand... hope this helps. Let me know in case of questions.

**The python code**

```
import openpyxl
#Open Input File open (file1)
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1['Sheet1']
#Create new file for Output (file2)
wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active
#Add header to output file
ws2.cell(row=1,column=1).value = "BASE"
ws2.cell(row=1,column=2).value = "A/B"

# Iterate through each line in input file from row 2 (skipping header) to last row
for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=ws1.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=3):
    for col, cell in enumerate(row):
        if col == 0: #First column, write to output
            ws2.cell(cell.row, col+1).value = cell.value
        elif col == 1:
            if cell.value != "X": #2nd column, write to output if not X
                ws2.cell(cell.row, col+1).value = cell.value
        else: #2nd column, write 3rd column if X
                ws2.cell(cell.row, col+1).value = ws1.cell(cell.row, col+2).value

wb2.save('file2.xlsx')
```

**Output excel after running**

[image]

Comment: There's no need for a counter here. Just use values_only and create lists of the values.

Comment: Hi @CharlieClark - I yield to the master :-)